# Pedersen commitment on binary field $GF(2^n)$

Tags: finite-field

I am curious whether one can do Pedersen commitment on $GF(2^n)$. One method I thought of was to get a prime order multiplicative subgroup of $GF(2^n)$. But for efficiency and security, what would be an appropriate value of $n$ for a security strength of 128-bit security?

Comment: Pedersen commitments rely on the discrete logarithm being hard and that one had a ... more shacky security history in $GF(2^n)$ than $GF(p)$ (IIRC).

Comment: Thanks. You are right, just found the recent attack on GF(2^10000).

Comment: [The aftermath and considerations of the new record of 30750-Bit Binary Field Discrete Logarithm - 2020](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83336/18298)

Comment: I noticed that some recent zk proof systems such as Aurora (libiop) needs binary field. How would pedersen commitment work using such systems?